# How do I add a column, which has an incrementing integer value, but it only increments when the value in another column changes

Tags: postgresql

Let's say I have the following walletid's

```
walletid
ab2
ab2
cd3
```

now I want to add an id to change it to this:

```
id     walletid
1      ab2
1      ab2
2      cd3
```

Comment: You can try with update trigger

Comment: How is the order defined?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```
SELECT wallets.walletid, wallets_distinct_ids.id
FROM wallets INNER JOIN
(SELECT walletid, row_number() OVER () as id
 FROM 
 (SELECT DISTINCT walletid
  FROM wallets) AS wallets_distinct) AS wallets_distinct_ids
ON wallets.walletid =  wallets_distinct_ids.walletid
```

Explanation:

1. First, we create a query that selects distinct values of `walletid`
2. We take the query from pt. 1 and use it as source in FROM clause.  now, you can add the window function to count rows. This query assigns distinct id for every distinct `walletid` value
3. Now We can use the query from pt.2 as source in FROM clause, joining it with your main table to assign the distinct id for every `walletid`